# Issue with Kendo Angular 2 Dialog

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

I am getting this error when trying to integrate the Kendo Dialog in Angular 2. I integrated Grid, Button, dropdowns successfully.

ERROR in ./~/@progress/kendo-angular-dialog/dist/es/dialog.component.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@telerik/kendo-theme-default/styles/packages/dialog' in 'C:\Projects\AMDS\amd_ui\node_modules\@progress\kendo-angular-dialog\dist\es'

Please let me know.

Comment: I see it is happening in the new dialog 0.13.0 version and not the previous 0.12.3 version. Though don't know what was fixed since 0.12.3 version of the dialog. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the corresponding issue:

https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular2/issues/110

Comment: Thank you - will follow that.

Comment: Thanks - confirming fixed in 0.13.1.