# Issue with Dropdowns in Angular 2 Kendo dialog

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

When I create a Kendo Combobox or Kendo dropdown - the values are being shown outside the dialog!

Here is the [link](http://embed.plnkr.co/HOKXyTmR07BGij4WDvxv/): you will see that when you click on the Add new button.

We could not use dialog version 0.13.0 because of this issue - no idea if this was resolved in that release.

[Issue with Kendo Angular 2 Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40922141/issue-with-kendo-angular-2-dialog)

Comment: See this in the latest version 0.13.1 as well.

Comment: This issue linked below is now fixed and the problem should be resolved. Please let us know if this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in the Popup positioning logic. The issue is logged in the public Github tracker:

https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular2/issues/115

Follow the Github thread for more details.